# Specifying the Index Font Size to be Other Than Normalsize or Small

Tags: fontsize, indexing, imakeidx, idxlayout, lipsum

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\makeindex
%\usepackage{idxlayout}
\usepackage[font=small]{idxlayout}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\indexsetup{othercode=\large}

\begin{document}
\Large
A sentence.\index{HEADING@\textbf{HEADING}!\textbf{Subheading}!\lipsum[3]}

\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

which produces the Index:

[image]

In the above, I have successfully specified the font size of the index to be `small`. The approach I used will also handle a `normalsize` font, as well.

Unfortunately, any other font size seems not to be recognized.

In order to accommodate a `large` font in the index, I have tried using `\indexsetup{othercode=\large}` at the same time eliminating `[font=small]`. Although I do not get an error, no change of font size occurs in the index.

QUESTION: How may I specify in the preamble, the font size for the Index for fonts other than `normalsize` or `small`. (It seems to me that without any specification, the font size of the index is taken from the font size of the document---but I would like to be able to produce a font size in the index different from that of the document, and not be limited to either a `normalsize` or `small` font in the index.) Also---

Does anyone know why the comma and page number in the MWE appear after the `lipsum` index entry? For future reference, how may I have the comma and page number placed on the ending line of the index entry when using `\lipsum`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for normal text the comma is inline but the lipsum macros end with an explicit end of paragraph so the page number and comma are a new paragraph.

For the font, the `idxlayout` package you are using provides `\indexfont` so you can use

`\renewcommand\indexfont{\Huge}`

or whatever you want. The `small` font key option is just a shorthand for common case, the package has:

`\def\ila@fo@small{\renewcommand*{\indexfont}{\small}}`

Comment: Many thanks for answering both parts of this question; incidentally, would you know of a simple way to keep the comma and page number on the same line as the entry when using `lipsum`? or should I, perhaps, pose that as a separate question sometime?

Comment: `\lipsum*` I think avoids the paragraph, but why do you care it's only dummy text, just write `abc xyz` unstead.

Comment: Aesthetics, I guess. Thank you for the suggestion.